# JavaScript - Why does the increment operator modify immutable strings?

Tags: javascript, string, immutability, nan

In JavaScript, strings are immutable. That means any operation on them returns a new object. Methods like `trim`, `replace` and `slice` don't modify the existing string.

However, I was playing around in jsconsole and found an exception

```
string = "string";
string + 37;
=> "string37"
string;
=> "string"
```

The original string hadn't changed here. Here's what happens when I apply the increment operator on the string. Here I am expecting to see `string` returned.

```
string++;
=> NaN
string
=> NaN
```

I was trying to see whether this would return `strinh`, like it would in some other languages.

Regardless of whether `string++` would work, it shouldn't modify existing string objects. Yet it did just that. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
var baz = "string";
baz = 5;
```

Certainly we have not modified the value of the string `"string"` by assigning `baz` to `5`. Instead, we have simply done away with the string altogether and put the value `5` in its place. Similarly, your example does not alter any strings by assigning your variable to `NaN`.

You expect the variable `string` to be a *constant*, but it's not. Furthermore, constant variables and immutable values are different things. You haven't changed the immutable string `"string"` into `NaN`; you have substituted the immutable value `"string"` for a completely different value, `NaN`.

Your operations *create* new values by *using* the immutable string as an operand.

Consider a real constant variable in an environment that supports the `const` keyword:

```
> const foo = 5;
> foo++
  5
```

Now consider a constant variable that is an object:

```
> const bar = {};
> bar.baz = 5
> bar
  { baz: 5 }
> bar = 10;
> bar
  { baz: 5 }
```

In this case, we mutated the value (because the value is not immutable) but could not alter *which* value the variable contains. Your example does not use constant variables, so the variable `string` can freely change its value.

Comment: This answer is perfectly explained. I will accept this

Answer (score 4):

That `++` operator works similarly to:

```
string = string + 1;
```

So, you are re-assigning to that variable. (while the original string remains immutable)

If you run `string = string + 1` yourself, you'll notice it results in `string1`. This is because the `1` is being converted into a string and then treated as an "append". (again, never modifying the original string *value*)

However, the `++` does not attempt to coerce anything, it simply attempts to add a non-number (ie: `string`) to a number (`1`) and the result is `NaN`.

Comment: A number added to a string returns a string. In my case, `string = string + 1` and `string += 1` both return `string1`. `string++` returns `NaN`. If I call string again, `NaN` appears. This means the string was modified

Comment: @user4703663 The string was not modified, but the variable now contains a different value.

Comment: Well, the `++` operator isn't **completely** identical to that code. `string + 1`   ends up casting `1` as a string, appending to the original and returning a new value. The `++` doesn't perform that casting, instead it tries to add a non-number to a number, resulting in `NaN`

Comment: Regardless, the point is that the `string` _variable_ simply contains a new value, but the original string value was never mutated.